# Shall i sign my app with my Production Certificate or Provisioning Profile Distribution?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

Im a solo developer that made a game app and a game lite app.

Now i wane send them to app store.

Do i need to create two Provisioning Profile of type Distribution, or can i select my auto generated (says recommended) iPhone Distribution for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already created distribution provisioning profile for your apps - you need to create and select it for publishing it to the app store. Your lite and full versions need two separate provisioning profiles unless you are upgrading the content through in app purchases.

Detailed explanation:

Usually for debugging you either use the XCode generated team provisioning profile or developer provisioning profile.

For pushing to the app store you should use the Distribution provisioning profile.

XCode provisioning profile recommendations are very useful when you are automating builds in continuous integration process. Since you are the only developer I guess it doesn't hurt choosing the exact profile from the list of profiles.